# How to count happy numbers

Tags: java

As an assignment I need to count the amount of happy numbers* in a given range. I did most of that already:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputLowerRange = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String inputUpperRange = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int lowerRange = Integer.parseInt(inputLowerRange);
        int upperRange = Integer.parseInt(inputUpperRange);

       Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++)
            while(lowerRange>0) {
                upperRange += (lowerRange % 10)*(lowerRange % 10); 
                lowerRange /=10;
            }

        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
            
            
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Now the code just needs to count the happy numbers* present within that range. I understand it is best done with:

```
if ............... counter++
```

but how exactly would I need to do it?

*A happy number is a number which eventually reaches 1 when replaced by the sum of the square of each digit. 13 is a happy number because 1^2 + 3^2 = 10
And 1^2 + 0^2 = 1, thus 13 is a happy number.

Comment: What is the condition to be a happy number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Programming_example

Comment: It would be easier to include the condition that makes a happy number in the question instead of just linking to Wikipedia. Make it easy for people to help you. Don't send them down some wikipedia rabbit hole and forget about your question.

Comment: Figured i would just make the question short and compact. But what you say does make sense, ill work on it.

Comment: `sum of the square of each digit` will be loop until its sum is either 1 (happy) or 4(unhappy)

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i=lowerRange;i<=upperRange;i++)
{
  int num=i,sum=0,rem;
  while(sum!=1 && sum!=4)
  {
    sum=0;
    while(num!=0)
    {
      rem=num%10;
      sum+=(rem*rem);
      num/=10;
    }
    num=sum;
  }
  if(sum==1)
    counter++
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

the issue with your code is you are making direct changes to `lowerRange` and `upperRange` which will result in not iterating properly. You need to use temp variables for those. Also you forgot this condition `while(sum!=1 && sum!=4){}`

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>(); //what's this for?
for (int i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++)
  while(lowerRange>0) { // missed one outer while loop
    upperRange += (lowerRange % 10)*(lowerRange % 10); // changes to upperRange 
    lowerRange /=10; // changes to lowerRange 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isHappy(null, 11));
    }

    public static boolean isHappy(Set<Integer> previousNumbers, int number) {
        if (previousNumbers == null) previousNumbers = new HashSet<>();
        else if (previousNumbers.contains(number)) return false;
        if (number == 4) return true;
        int length = getNumberLength(number);
        int subNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int digit = getNumberDigit(number, i);
            subNumber += digit * digit;
        }
        previousNumbers.add(number);
        return isHappy(previousNumbers, subNumber);
    }

    public static int getNumberDigit(int number, int index) {
        int pow = (int) Math.pow(10, index);
        return (number % (pow * 10)) / pow;
    }

    public static int getNumberLength(int number) {
        int length = 0;
        for (long temp = 1; temp <= number; temp *= 10)
            length++;
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error at the "return isHappy(subNumber);"
It says: The method isHappy(Set<Integer>, int) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (int)
boolean Main.isHappy(Set<Integer> previousNumbers, int number)

What exactly does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi @AaronVersteegh, sorry for answering so late. I forgot to pass "previousNumbers" to the recursive "isHappy". This code should work! Keep in mind that this code will break when using negative numbers (Happy numbers are only defined for the natural range).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static boolean isHappy(int n) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    while (n > 1 && !set.contains(n)) {
        set.add(n);
        n = String.valueOf(n).chars()
            .map(c -> c - '0')
            .reduce(0, (sum, i) -> sum + i * i);
    }
    return n == 1;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt())
        .filter(i -> isHappy(i))
        .count());
}
```